# How to open, load and plot a numpy file in python?

Tags: python, numpy

I need to open, load and plot a numpy file in python? 
This is my version:

```
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

 plt.plotfile('traces1.npy')
 plt.show()
```

This is my trace that I need to plot it:

```
[[-0.00824758 -0.0081808  -0.00811402 ..., -0.0077236  -0.00765425
  -0.00762086]]
```

But I had those error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "traces_plot.py", line 3, in <module>
    plt.plotfile('trace1.npy')
  File "C:\Users\user\WinPython-64bit-2.7.6.4\python-2.7.6.amd64\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2311, in plotfile
    checkrows=checkrows, delimiter=delimiter, names=names)
  File "C:\Users\user\WinPython-64bit-2.7.6.4\python-2.7.6.amd64\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mlab.py", line 2103, in csv2rec
    for row in reader:
_csv.Error: line contains NULL byte
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I already put what I read in my  script

Comment: Include `'trace1.npy'` if you can.

Comment: I edit it but I don't think that the name of my trace would change any thing.

Comment: It's pretty clear that the error is telling you that you have a Null character in your numpy file, this is why @MYGz is asking to post the file, but if you think is not needed you are free to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: I have already solve it, thank you for your help ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plt.plotfile()` expects a csv (text file). A file named `'traces1.npy'` is typically a binary. Use `np.load()` to load your data and plot later:

```
data = np.load('traces1.npy')
plt.plot(data[0])
plt.show()
```

You need `data[0]` for this array (as shown in your question):

```
[[-0.00824758, -0.0081808,  -0.00811402, -0.0077236,  -0.00765425,
  -0.00762086]]
```

Note the double `[`, i.e. `[[` and `]]`.

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me you can load the whole npy file and plot its data.

## import the library of NumPy

`import numpy`

## load the data file

`data = np.load('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/YOLO/test_image_disp.npy')
print(data)` #optional

## plot the histogram

`plt.hist(data.ravel(),256,[0,256]); plt.show()`

[image]

Comment: Could you add some details on what and why and possibly add an example output/result? It is hard to determine if this is a better answer or if it even is an answer.